# Проблема с кодировкой в requests_html?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, requests-html

Не получается спарсить заголовок сайта в правильной кодировке.

```
>>> from requests_html import HTMLSession
>>> session = HTMLSession()
>>> r = session.get('https://pm.by/live.html')
>>> print(r.encoding)
WINDOWS-1251
>>> r.html.xpath('//title/text()')
['������ Live � ������ �� ����� ���� (�� ���� �����): �� ��������']
```

У сайта кодировка cp1251, когда делаю xpath-запрос получаю кракозябры.
Кракозябры не хотят перегоняться даже в байты, методом encode.

```
>>> r.html.xpath('//title/text()')[0].encode('cp1251')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/encodings/cp1251.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема полностью описана в ошибке:)

Есть ряд символов, которые нельзя заэнкодить.

Поэтому, вам надо прописывать:

`r.html.xpath('//title/text()')[0].encode('cp1251', 'ignore')`

Comment: Этот ряд — все кириллические символы. Почему их не получается заэнкодить?